# How to increase upload file size more than 1 MB on Nginx / WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, nginx

It seems like I'm stuck at 1MB to upload files on WP.

I changed the php.ini value. I see the right value with phpinfo() and also in the upload media page of WP.

I changed the client_max_body_size value in Nginx configuration files. I changed it in the HTTP block of nginx.conf + location and server blocks of the specific site's configuration. Still not working!

I'm out of ideas...

Comment: Just to confirm, when changing the `client_max_body_size` in nginx, did you restart nginx or reload its config? Also, what message do you see when trying to upload larger files -- either on-screen messages or in error logs?

Comment: Yes I restarted Nginx.
From the WP admin, I get 'Failed to write file to disk'. It's written under 'file-name has failed to upload'. I see the progress bar go to 100% then the message appears.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using multisite, there is a network admin settings page with a Max upload file size field, make sure this is also set correctly.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Network_Admin_Settings_Screen

Answer (score 0):

Update your `/php.ini` file *(or create one if doesn't exist)*. 
Do something like below;

```
upload_max_filesize = 1000M // toggle your values
post_max_size = 2000M // toggle your values
memory_limit = 3000M // toggle your values
file_uploads = On // toggle your values
max_execution_time = 180 // toggle your values
```

You could also try editing `/wp-config.php` ie;

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '3000M'); // set
```

And / or; you could update your `.htaccess` file and do the below:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M // toggle your values
php_value post_max_size 2000M // toggle your values
php_value memory_limit 3000M // toggle your values
php_value max_execution_time 180 // toggle your values
php_value max_input_time 180 // toggle your values
```

*I* would recommend just uploading via FTP to avoid the CMS file size limits.

Comment: These values are all OK based on phpinfo().

Also I'm using Nginx, not Apache.

On the WP upload page, I see the upload file size correctly too.